# Default location for compiled js files in create-react-app --typescript

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I'm using the typescript version of create-react-app. I'm only using `npm start` (not `npm build`).

I'd like to inspect the js files create by typescript but I can can't find a build folder. Where are the compiled files saved?

Comment: npm start will strat via webpack-dev-server. webpack-dev-server using caching for output files. there is no directory. try to build with other [options]https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts/template#making-a-progressive-web-app)

Comment: Thank you @JurajKocan. If you want to make your comment into an answer I'd be happy to upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

npm start will strat via webpack-dev-server. webpack-dev-server using caching for output files. there is no directory. try to build with other [option](http://npm%20start%20will%20strat%20via%20webpack-dev-server.%20webpack-dev-server%20using%20caching%20for%20output%20files.%20there%20is%20no%20directory.%20try%20to%20build%20with%20other)